# Kernel module raised warning and taints kernel

Tags: c, kernel, kernel-module, taint

I'm just writing a Linux kernel module and getting a warning message that my kernel is tainted:

```
[ 1194.552013] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 1194.552639] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 176 at /build/linux-mcJ30I/linux-3.16.7-ckt20/block/blk.h:231 generic_make_request_checks+0x46a/0x480()
[ 1194.552639] Modules linked in: <my kernel muldule>(O) <various other Standard kernel modules>
[ 1194.552639] CPU: 0 PID: 176 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: G           O  3.16.0-4-586 #1 Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u1
[ 1194.552639] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[ 1194.552639]  ebeb3b70 ebeb3b70 c103bf71 c14f2d68 00000000 000000b0 c1520644 000000e7
[ 1194.552639]  c11ddd1a 000000e7 c11ddd1a ec0d4800 edcb5c00 ffffffff ebeb3b80 c103c032
[ 1194.552639]  00000009 00000000 ebeb3bf8 c11ddd1a 06010006 000001a7 00000000 00000000
[ 1194.552639] Call Trace:
[ 1194.552639]  [<c103bf71>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x81/0xa0
[ 1194.552639]  [<c11ddd1a>] ? generic_make_request_checks+0x46a/0x480
[ 1194.552639]  [<c11ddd1a>] ? generic_make_request_checks+0x46a/0x480
...
```

The message just appears once, my module is working as it should and I'm not getting any Oops message or kernel Panic or similar.

I read several questions, answers and tutorials ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/linux-what-is-a-tainted-kernel), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252165/what-does-kernel-tainted-mean) or [here](http://timedigit.blogspot.co.at/2013/03/tainted-kernel-what-to-do.html)) but basically all I found out is that the currently running kernel is not supported by the community (anymore) and can't be debugged by the community. For me, this is obvious since my kernel module is installed and they don't have the source of it.

So for me it seems like there is nothing dangerous with that warning message, is that correct? I already tried to find an error for several hours but I didn't find one. So is the message just showing up because I'm using my kernel module?

**Edit:** I don't know if it's important but I'm running Linux kernel 3.16.0-4-586

Comment: This warning is **unrelated to tainted kernel**. It just says that you have fired warning condition at [block/blk.h:231](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/blk.h?v=3.16#L231). Looking into sources reaveals, that function is not expected to be called with irq disabled (e.g. after `spin_lock_irqsave` or within interrupt). And description of the function tells the reason of such requirement.