# Why is the kernel Tainted after softlockup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I am using `Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS` and I am running my program that have one real time thread with 100% core usage, in this situation kernel says in syslog like below

```
kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s! …
kernel: print all modules …
```

And after I see soft lockup kernel says in syslog like below

```
kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 53590 Comm: … Tainted: G OEL … #1
```

And after see above message, my server is hang completely and I have to reboot it. whiles my server have many cores, and only one core is 100%.

My kernel version is 4.15.

I have four questions:

1. Why my server is hang and freeze completely? (I have many cores, and only one of them is full)
2. How to resolve that to not happened again?
3. Why after soft lockup I see kernel tainted?
4. How to say kernel (watchdog) to this situation is not BUG and it is normal? (any configuration or disable way)

Note: I don't want to know meaning of tainted. because I know some of about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27252165/1539100). I want to know about why my soft lockup cause to kernel tainted ( My server has many cores and only one of them is 100% core usage and another cores is free)? (in my situation)

Answer (score -1):

The first 2 questions are too generic, so I focus on the last 2 questions:

Q: Why after soft lockup I see kernel tainted?

A: Usually, kernel is considered "tainted" because one or more kernel modules loaded are NOT licensed under the GPL license. This "tainted" word is important in kernel log because non-tainted kernel crash cases have higher priority in kernel community.

Q: How to say kernel (watchdog) to this situation is not BUG and it is normal?

A: Not fully understand your question. Usually, soft lockup is caused by some code (for example, in kernel thread, or interrupt handler) doesn't release CPU (for example, disable interrupt), there is one soft lockup watchdog thread per CPU core, once this thread has no chance to run in a long period, watchdog will be triggered.

Comment: I have not generic question, I have question about my situation. my question is why my server is freeze when only one of my core (thread) is 100 %

Comment: your answer is not my answer, because my question is, why my soft lockup cause kernel crash( if kernel tainted equal to kernel crash  ( I am not sure ))?, but you say the meaning of tainted.

Comment: from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/27255536/1539100 you can see kernel tainted is not equal to kernel crash. so I have question about this situation to why my server is freeze if kernel is not crash? or how can I know to is my kernel is crash or not?

Comment: about second answer my question is, is there any way to configure and say watchdog to longer wait? or can I disable it?

Comment: You can refer to /proc/sys/kernel/softlockup_thresh and Documentation/lockup-watchdogs.txt